# Images in Android GridView changes. How?

Tags: android, image, gridview, dynamic

> I am using the standard gridview source for my app. The problem which i face is that, when i scroll the images in the gridview, the images change dynamically everytime, having wrong images at the positions. For reference below is the code i use......

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
    // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
    cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, // Which columns to return
            null,       // Return all rows
            null,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
    // Get the column index of the Thumbnails Image ID
    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));




    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageSelection.class);
            // passing array index
            i.putExtra("imageIndex_from_Activity", position);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

**> ImageAdapter class**

```
 private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context localContext) {
        context = localContext;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView picturesView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            picturesView = new ImageView(context);
            // Move cursor to current position
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            // Get the current value for the requested column
            int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            // Set the content of the image based on the provided URI
            picturesView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID));
            picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            picturesView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            picturesView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(80, 80));
        }
        else {
            picturesView = (ImageView)convertView;
        }
        return picturesView;
    }
}
```

> Attaching screenshots, 1.Before Scrolling 2.Scrolled down and scrolled up again.

[image: before scrolling]

[image: when scrolled up again]

> Why does the order changes??

Comment: unrelated to the question, but use a cursoradapter, it contains lots of stuff you are doing yourself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only setting the image on new views.

Do the following:

```
if (convertView == null) {
    picturesView = new ImageView(context);
    picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    picturesView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    picturesView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(80, 80));    
} else {
    picturesView = (ImageView)convertView;
}
// Move cursor to current position
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
// Get the current value for the requested column
int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
// Set the content of the image based on the provided URI
picturesView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID));
```

Comment: Yeah I just noticed I pasted before the bracket.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that when you use convertView it stores old data form the first records. Convert view is used to avoid layout inflation from resource which costs you time and memory. You should use the old inflated view, but set new data.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    ImageView picturesView;  
    if (convertView == null) {  
        picturesView = new ImageView(context);  
    }  
    else {  
        picturesView = (ImageView)convertView;  
    } 
       cursor.moveToPosition(position);  
        // Get the current value for the requested column  
        int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);  
        // Set the content of the image based on the provided URI  
        picturesView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(  
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID));  
        picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);  
        picturesView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);  
        picturesView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(80, 80));  
    return picturesView;  
}
```